# Feedback & diagnostics: "Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization"

Tags: windows-10

I can't send feedback from Windows 10 anymore. Somehow I broke it, but I don't know how. I used to send issues to Microsoft regularly and was very glad to see many of them were fixed. Not anymore. Now when I try to send a feedback from any UWP application I see following message:

> Allow feedback
>
> We want you to send us feedback, but you need to adjust your
> privacy settings first. Please change your diagnostics and usage data
> setting to at least Basic. If you decide not to, you can still access the
> app but won't be able to send feedback.

There is a "Settings" link below. It links to the "Feedback & diagnostics" settings page. Directly after the mentioned header there is a message:

> *Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization.

My computer is not a member of a domain. It's Windows 10 Enterprise build 15063.413. Registered with MSDN subscription.

I tried all obvious Windows settings.

Then I tried to re-enable any disabled Windows services. The only ones I left disabled are:

- Web Management
- Shared PC Account Manager
- Smart Card
- Remote Registry
- Routing and Remote Access
- Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service

I did this because initially I disabled some services due to security concerns.
When re-enabling I set the startup type to "Manual" - so the system can start them when they are needed. At least I guess it's how it works.

Then of course I checked Group Policy editor, though I don't recall ever using it on this Windows installation. I checked if any setting was set there and I found nothing. Every option I checked had default value (which I believe is "unset").

I'm pretty out of ideas for now. I know I must have broken it. It worked, I played with the system, now it doesn't work.

I had problems with developer tools in Edge, but I fixed them with re-enabling some Windows services. I'm pretty sure it's not the case here. Any ideas?

Comment: You have enabled all disabled services I presume?  Manual means the user has to start them......

Comment: Of course, enabling all services didn't help. I disabled some of them afterwards.

Comment: Some settings are dependent on other settings being enabled.  Can you verify which settings you have disabled?

Comment: All related settings are enabled. All except the one which is hidden, so I can't enable it.

Comment: If you will submit a screenshot, instead of asking if "...." is enabled that will help this process along.